# Hosting HIPPO CMS

Tags: java, linux, postgresql, repository, hippocms

I have built my own hippo project based on hippo-maven-archetype.
I have prepared the PostgreSQL configuration of repository and created hippo database.
Then I've built my app and run it by maven (mvn -Pcargo.run -Drepo.path=storage).
All is ok, Postgresql repository was initialized successsfully and hippo works.

Now I am trying to deploy my project on my Linux server, as described here, using tomcat 8 and java 8.
All is ok, **except that the repository does not initializing in any way.**

Cms Web-page always redirects to *localhost/cms/wicket/bookmarkable/org.hippoecm.frontend.NoRepositoryAvailablePage*.
    At tomcat startup there are no errors, but **also there are no messages about bootstrapping the repository**.
    After successful startup, log files contain exception: *java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The resource path [WEB-INF/storage] is not valid*

Tomcat java command prompt (as ps shows:)

/usr/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/apache-tomcat/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -server -Xmx512m -Xms128m -XX:PermSize=128m **-Drepo.path=storage -Drepo.config=file:/opt/apache-tomcat/conf/repository.xml -Drepo.bootstrap=true -Dlog4j.configuration=file:/opt/apache-tomcat/conf/log4j.xml** -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/opt/apache-tomcat/endorsed -classpath /opt/apache-tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/apache-tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar -Dcatalina.base=/opt/apache-tomcat -Dcatalina.home=/opt/apache-tomcat -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/apache-tomcat/temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start

Any ideas?

Comment: Hippo CMS 7.9.x is not Java 8 runtime compliant yet as far as I know. This is coming soon. Not sure if you run into that issue. You might check if the database get's populated in postgres. I also would advise you to put the repo.path to an external location outside of the app container. Something like  -Drepo.path=/opt/hippo-storage.

Comment: Yes, thank you, everything works fine under java 7 and tomcat 7. But as far as I know applications compiled with java 7 must work under java 8 without recompilation.

Answer (score 1):

It's a best practice to put your repository storage outside of your web application. I would advise you to explicitly set the storage location by using the **repo.path** system property to a **full qualified location** on the filesystem instead of a relative path like you do now. With Tomcat you could specify this in your setenv.sh file by appending the following parameter to your CATALINA_OPTS.

```
CATALINA_OPTS="-Xmx1024m -Drepo.path=/opt/cms-storage/"
```

You also need to take into account that the configured workspace will be extracted to a separate file within this storage directory, so if you change something within the repository.xml you will probably have to change the existing workspace.xml as well. As of version 7.9.7 Hippo supports running the entire stack on Java 8. See the [release notes](http://www.onehippo.org/library/about/release-notes/7.9.7-release-notes.html) for more information and what has changed.